# How to filter text array with items in list case insensitively in Supabase?

Tags: supabase

I have a text array (`text[]`) in Supabase. Let's say it's like this:

`["Car", "Red", "New"]`

I would like to get this row by filtering with list of words. So when I query `new` or `car` or `red` or any combination of these words, I should get the row with the array above. In other words, querying `text[]` with list of items.

So this query with `["new", "red"]` should return the column above.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: @Thierry Sorry no, I ditched Supabase.